# Upload multiple files with CarrierWave as single records in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm sorry, but I'm stuck.
How can I upload multiple files with CarrierWave and save them one by one? 
I don't want to have an array with multiple files, but each file should be saved individually. I have a form that accepts multiple files. But I only find ways to save the whole upload as one entry. How can I create single objects from params with multiple files?

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

Here is my controller:

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @image = Image.new
  end

  def create
    @image = Image.new(image_params)
    if @image.save
      flash[:primary] = "Image uploaded"
      redirect_to images_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def index
    @images = Image.all
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  private
  def image_params
    params.require(:image).permit({image: []}, :image_title, :image_file_size,  :image_content_type, :image_description, :category_id, :image_creation_date, :image_uploader)
  end
end
```

This code works. The problem is that I don't know how to iterate over the parameters. I can access the individual parameters though. But I can't store them one by one.

Here my trial:

```
  def create
    image_params['image'].each do |img|
      @image = Image.new(img)
      @image.save
    end
    redirect_to images_path
  end
```

The error is:

```
ArgumentError Exception: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile passed.
```

I understand that I don't have a hash, but only the individual files and that this is the error. But I don't know how else to do it.

Comment: Can you share the code in your controller `create` action? If you have all the required data in your params you will simply need to iterate over your params and create each object.

Comment: Share some code that what you have tried so far, so that we can help you.

Comment: edited my question